# how to remove badge notification symbol from app icon in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icons, apple-push-notifications

I am facing a problem with removing the badge number which always shows a red "1" on app icon notification symbol where there is no notification pending.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];`

Comment: How did it become 1 in the first place? I wonder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the below in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, some any methods in app life cycle..

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

When it is set to zero it should not show any badges.